# Why can't this query work in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I auto generated an index creation query in SQL Server 2008 R2 and tried in on SQL Server 2000. It didn't work and had errors. Can someone have a look at this query? Thanks!

```
USE [DBDBDB]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index_FullReturn] ON [dbo].[tbl_Ev_Data] 
(
    [OffDateTime] ASC,
    [Type] ASC,
    [Tag] ASC,
    [Name] ASC,
    [Description] ASC,
    [Category] ASC

) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Please post the **complete and exact** error message(s) you're getting - that would be tremendously helpful to figure out what's wrong!!

Answer (score 2):

Please check the syntax on MSDN, few of the **"with options"** are not availabe on SQL Server 2000. Like online,Allow_Row_Lock ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258260%28SQL.80%29.aspx